# Access Ember application instance from outside (cordova)

Tags: javascript, cordova, ember.js

I want to acccess my Ember application from the outside (cordova build). I thought it would be possible this way:

```
window.App.__container__.lookup('controller:beacon-manager').get('currentBeacons').pushObjects(beacons);
```

But my the App is not availlable on window when inside cordova. Is there a clean way to access  my ember app from inside Cordova? The purpose is to  trigger Ember code from within a custom plugin.

Comment: Is window.App defined? If ur using ember-cli, I think the app will be available on window with the name u specify in package.json. just take that name run it in Em.String.classify(name in package.json). That should be the name of the property on the window object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-export-application-global

With this addon you can have your app export the app name to the top level of global scope.  i.e.  `Window.YourAppName`